# Can't listen on remote address

Tags: database, couchdb, hosting, couchdb-2.0, couchdb-mango

so I installed couchdb on my VPS using snap, it only listened on 127.0.0.1 and this was not ok for me as It's not practical to ssh on a production environment, I would like it to listen on my external IP so I set in the /var/snap/couchdb/1/local.ini the following

```
[httpd]
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

however it still didn't work, using  `lsof -i -n -P | grep LISTEN` gave me the following which shows its still listening on the local host:

```
sshd      1039     root    3u  IPv4  15918      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      1039     root    4u  IPv6  15927      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
postgres  4520 postgres    6u  IPv6  23892      0t0  TCP [::1]:5432 (LISTEN)
postgres  4520 postgres    7u  IPv4  23893      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5432 (LISTEN)
nginx    15991     root    6u  IPv4  72755      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx    15991     root    7u  IPv6  72756      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx    15992 www-data    6u  IPv4  72755      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx    15992 www-data    7u  IPv6  72756      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
beam.smp 17728     root   24u  IPv4  85538      0t0  TCP *:4000 (LISTEN)
epmd     29600     root    3u  IPv4 307366      0t0  TCP *:4369 (LISTEN)
epmd     29600     root    4u  IPv6 307367      0t0  TCP *:4369 (LISTEN)
beam     30374     root    8u  IPv4 311044      0t0  TCP *:37659 (LISTEN)
beam     30374     root   16u  IPv4 311055      0t0  TCP *:5986 (LISTEN)
beam     30374     root   18u  IPv4 311057      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:5984 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out that in new versions couchdb listens externally on port 5986 AND internally on 5984, not sure if this was triggered by adding 0.0.0.0 to bind address or not.